# What does `.inside()` do when used by Jenkins to run docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

What does `.inside` do:

```
    docker.image('node:7-alpine').inside {
```

E.g. near the top of https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins will create a container based on the image received as parameter and then excute commands inside this container. The workspace will be automatically shared with the container.

Comment: Simple and concise. Nice answer.